# Fast two table search?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE item(
code TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY(name, code)) ENGINE = INNODB

CREATE TABLE buffer(
code TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(name, code)) ENGINE = INNODB
```

I have the above tables. I want to do the following with the fastest way possible:

When adding a new `code and name pair` in table `buffer`, I want to be sure the pair doesn't exist on any of the 2 tables.
Is there any really fast way to do this or I have to 1st search table `item` and then search table `buffer` and then add the item?

Comment: Use triggers and let the database take care of it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html ([How to prevent insertion when using a trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255730/create-trigger-prevent-insert))

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: If you look at [the accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4255782/1567737) 80% of your question is answered, you merely have to convert the answer there to suit your needs.

Comment: To throw it in another direction, can't you add a column `buffered BOOLEAN` to the `item` table and place it all in one table? that would be the most optimized way to solve this as you already have an unique key that will enforce what you ask.

Comment: This is true, but the buffer contains data who can be invalid...

Comment: Then `validate( items where buffered = true )` (pseudo-code)

Comment: I can't do this fast enough. So I just store them and do this when I can.

Comment: Then call `validate( items where buffered = true )` when you can ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following tutorials check (during registration) if the username/email is already taken or not.

[**Username Availability Check using PHP and Jquery - YouHack.me**](http://youhack.me/2010/05/04/username-availability-check-in-registration-form-using-jqueryphp/)

[**Check Username Availability during registeration - SourceCodester**](http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/6426/phpmysqli-creating-forum-part-13-users-registering.html)

After looking at the above two sources, you'll get an idea of how to check the username availability live during regeneration, using jQuery's Ajax functionality.
**Than you can implement the same functionality in your application, *instead of username availability you'll check for the code and name***(code's name) presence. If its present, it will display a message that the code is already present, if its not present already it won't display a message.

I hope this helped you.