# How to check same id have multiple values in another column?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

i have team member table and  team table.
In team member table have , three columns are there teamid, staff_id  and stafftype(leader or technician). Only one leader (staff_type column value) will comes in one team. So when i insert data to team member table i need to check whether any leader is there in same team.

How to show an error message that "already have leader in this team"?

```
team_id   staff_id   stafftype
1          2        leader
2          1        other
3          8        other
1          5        Technician
2          3        Other
1          4        Leader //This should not come. becoz already teamid-1 have Leader When trying to save from frond end, need to show error message ie;"already have leader in this team"
```

**Modal**

```
  public function addteam_memb($datas){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('team_members');
    $querySS = $this->db->get()->result();

    if(array_search('1', array_column($querySS, 'team_id')) !== false) {
    return 1;
}
 else {
    $insert_id = 0;
    if ( ! empty($datas))
    {
      $this->db->insert('team_members', $datas);
      $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
 }

 }
```

**Controller**

```
public function editteammember(){

    $getaddstafftype = $this->input->post( 'getaddstafftype' );
    $getaddstaffname = $this->input->post( 'getaddstaffname' );
    $getteamid = $this->input->post('getteamid');
    $getstatus = $this->input->post('getstatus');

    //if ( ! empty($getaddstaffname) ) 
    if ( ! empty($getaddstaffname) && ! empty($getaddstafftype) ) 
{
    foreach ($getaddstaffname as $key => $value ) 
    {
        $data['Staff_id'] = $value;
        $data['Staff_type'] = $getaddstafftype[$key];
        $data['team_id'] = $getteamid[$key];
        $data['status'] = "active";
      $value = $this->mastertable_model->addteam_memb($data);

    }

    if($value == 1)
        {
            echo "Already have leader in this team";
        }
        else
        {
            //$this->load->view('team_memb_creation');        
        }

}
```

}

Comment: You probably need before insert trigger. To validate there isnt a leader on that team

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create trigger prevent insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255730/create-trigger-prevent-insert)

Answer (score 0):

MODEL :

```
   public function add_team_memb(){


    $this->db->select('NEXT VALUE FOR team_seq as team_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $team_id = $row['team_id'];
    }

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('team_member');
    $querySS = $this->db->get()->result();

    if(array_search('1', array_column($querySS, 'team_id')) !== false) {

        return 1;
    }
    else {

        $datateam_memb = array(
            'team_id' => $team_id,
            'staff_id' => 3,
            'stafftype' => 'leader',

        );
        $insert_id = 0;
        if ($this->db->insert("team_member", $datateam_memb)) {
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return $team_id;

    }


}
```

CONTROLLER ::

```
 public function addteammember()
{

    $value = $this->Admin_model->add_team_memb();

    if($value == 1)
    {
        ///pass message in view leader is already in team
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('team_memb_creation');        
    }

}
```

Comment: i Have updated my recent code. Plz check the expected output

Comment: actually team_id column allow to insert same value.But only one staff type leader for the specific team

Comment: for the same team_id i have multiple team members with stafftype(leader or technician)

Comment: While insert to team_members table,i need to check whether the team_id have only one Leader then skip insert to database